# How to add data in refinerycms engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Has anyone else run into a mass assignment error when trying to create a new piano?

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Refinery::Pianos::Admin::PianosController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, dimensions, manufactured_on(1i), manufactured_on(2i), manufactured_on(3i), upright, photo_id, description, position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up your model file and put this in there you will have more success:

```
attr_accessible :dimensions, :manufactured_on, :upright, :photo_id, :description, :position
```

The model file should look like this:

```
module Refinery
  module Pianos
    class Piano < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      self.table_name = 'refinery_pianos'

      attr_accessible :dimensions, :manufactured_on, :upright, :photo_id, :description, :position

      acts_as_indexed :fields => [:dimensions, :description]

      validates :dimensions, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

      belongs_to :photo, :class_name => '::Refinery::Image'
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that helps. I guess it's a bug in the version you're using but it's fixed in the Refinery CMS 2-0-stable branch.